# How many hours long "continuous video" can you shoot on Huawei P30 Lite 2019 model?

Tags: video

I want to shoot an extremely long video (almost 6-8 hours). Is the Huawei P30 Lite 2019 model BLE able to do it?

If not, for how many hours will it last?

Comment: Storage (including max allowed file size) and battery are two major limiting factors. Tune your camera app settings to whatever you like (FPS, resolution etc.) and record a video of a few minutes. Then estimate how much storage and battery it consumes. No answer here can be more realistic than this estimation.

Comment: Will the device be plugged in to a power source, or rely on its battery?

Comment: Note that if you can keep the screen off while shooting the video, the device will use significantly less power.

Comment: Also be aware some camera apps [restrict](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/111080/131553) video size //File system of device also plays a role (you can't record more than 4GB on ExFAT) // I would suggest do a trial run for as long as you want to actually record to avoid surprises

Comment: @beeshyams Is there a reason why "you can't record more than 4GB on ExFAT"? FAT32 has a file size limit of 4GB but ExFAt's file size limit is 16 exbibytes.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio sorry, it was a typo - I meant FAT32